# Problems authenticating through API key sent in headers WWW::Mechanize

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

To get a response from an API, the key must be sent as a header along with the request.  If I send it from the command line using `curl -Ss -H "APIKEY: KEY" https://www.example.com/some/stuff` the request succeeds. However, if I send it using

```
my $path = "https://www.example.com/some/stuff"
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->add_header('APIKEY'=>'KEY');
$mech->get($path);
```

I receive `Error GETing https://www.example.com/some/stuff: Can't connect to www.example.com:443 (Permission denied)`. How can I properly supply this header so I authenticate?

Comment: It seems to be working if I run it as any user, but if it's run by httpd as nobody, I get a failed connection. It turns out it isn't an authentication issue, it just can't connect at all. Why might that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a server side script that shows the output of headers from both examples and APIKEY was set identically in both cases. There were some differences in HTTP_ACCEPT / HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING and WWW::Mechanize adds some additional headers:

```
'downgrade-1.0' => '1'
'force-response-1.0' => '1'
'nokeepalive' => '1'
```

So I would suggest the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: It seems to be working if I run it as any user, but if it's run by httpd as nobody, I get a failed connection. It turns out it isn't an authentication issue, it just can't connect at all. Why might that be?

Comment: Honestly, I'd be guessing to answer that. There's a possibility that the server is detecting the user agent. Try:

    $mech->agent( 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_4; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.1 Safari/533.17.8' );

Comment: Sorry - that last comment was posted too early.

 Your best bet is to add some debug tracing to see what is happening during the connection attempt. Try the FAQ at http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize/FAQ.pod for some debugging tips.

I don't think it's the agent if you're not even establishing a connection. 

Add this before your get():

$mech->add_handler("request_send",  sub { shift->dump; return });
$mech->add_handler("response_done", sub { shift->dump; return });

and it might tell you something useful.